# How to add a customized InfoWindow to markers in google-maps swift ui?

Tags: swiftui, google-maps-markers, infowindow

i tried to make a view like bellow in SwiftUi without any success  [Customized info window swift ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDAvW.png)

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Add your code, what errors you are getting, what specifically isn't working, etc.

Comment: Hi Todd , thanks for commenting , the thing is i have tried several ways but i didn't get the result i want , i don't get any errors and for now i deleted all the codes that does't give me the result i want  , can you just check this image and tell if this view [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDAvW.png) is possible in swiftui

Answer (score 0):

Since this question doesn't have too much detail, I will be going off of some assumptions. First, I am assuming that you are calling the MapView through a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

I am not too familiar with the Google Maps SDK, but this is possible through the `GMSMapViewDelegate` Methods. After implementing the proper `GMSMapViewDelegate` method, you can use ZStacks to present the image that you would like to show.

For example:

```
struct MapView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var parentView: ContentView
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) {
        let mapView = GMSMapView()
        return mapView
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView
        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        //Use the proper Google Maps Delegate method to find out if a marker was tapped and then show the image by doing: parent.parentView.isShowingInformationImage = true. 
    }
}
```

In your SwiftUI view that you would like to put this MapView in, you can do the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingInformationImage = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if isShowingInformationImage {
                //Call the View containing the image
            }
            MapView(parentView: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Infowindow is called callout in MapKit. This wont work since the view will not be anchoted to the marker itself.